# UFT change default value of input parameter of all test cases

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, alm

I have 100 cases and all have the same parameter called testEnvirement = "Envirement1"

How can I change this parameter to "Envirement2" for all test cases?

From ALM or UFT is accepted

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

@ridvanzoro: Kindly find the working code below for the requirement mentioned above.

**Assumption\Future Modifications**

1)The below script will work for only one test to replace the string
2)If it need to work for multiple script, we need to simply add one for loop around the tag name `Future` in the code
3)The script name should be input either from a array or some other means according to your logic for all the script which needs the variable modification in single shot
4)This code is made to work for scripts in local and this can be easily adapted to the scripts saved in ALM\QC. Only we need to establish a connection to ALM via over VBScript

Kindly let me know if anything required in addition to this.

**Working Code**

```
string_to_replace="Envirement1"
replacing_value="Envirement2"
Dim qtApp
'Create the QTP Application object
Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application") 

'If QTP is notopen then open it
If  qtApp.launched <> True then 
qtApp.Launch 
End If 

'Make the QuickTest application visible
qtApp.Visible = True
test_name="C:\Users\u461322\Desktop\Timesheet\GUITest1"
REM Future
qtApp.Open test_name, False, False

'Get count of Action in a test
oActCount=qtApp.Test.Actions.Count
context = qtApp.Test.Actions(1).GetScript
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") 

objRegEx.Global = True 
objRegEx.Pattern =  string_to_replace
strNewString = objRegEx.Replace(context,replacing_value)
qtApp.Test.Actions(1).SetScript(strNewString)
qtApp.Test.Save
REM Future
qtApp.quit
Set qtApp = Nothing
Set objRegEx = Nothing
```

Comment: hi @mulla, I'm not looking for change text at script, I need to change default input parameter and i dont know where it stores

Comment: @ridvanzoro: We can do according to yours by the following way Line1:`Set oParams = qtApp.Test.ParameterDefinitions.GetParameters()`

Comment: Line 2:`oParams.Item(parameterName).Value = "Envirement2"`

Comment: Has to be added in the same file to do according to your purpose... Kindly let me know if this works